# SSIS quarter data freeze

Tags: ssis

I have the scenario where I need to load data for next quarter ,this data should be insert only and from next day 
data should be incremental load.For example for quarter 1 jan to 6 march .On 1 jan we have loaded historical load or first time insert and on 2 jan onwards it in incremental load. Now on 7 march we want fresh insert and from 8 march incremental load will run on newly insert data on 7 march. Like we want to lock the data from the quarter 1 jan to 6 march and fresh insert should happen on 7 march and 8 march incremental load should run on data loaded on 7 march. How to achieve this in ssis?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a calendar table defining those periods? do you have an existing SSIS package that just bulk loads everything? Is data ever back dated in the source system?

Comment: bulk loading is used.Main issue i am facing is how to freeze the quarter data?

Comment: Freeze just means don’t refresh it. So it really depends on what you already have. One way to approach is to write an expression that evaluates  the first date you want to refresh (delete and reload) from. This would be a long expression including ‘getdate()’ and ‘datepart’

Comment: that 3 months data is in production now,incremental load is happening everyday.now the scene is  we have to lock the quarter data in 4-5 th week of the quarter ie is around 4-9 april.Then fresh insert should take place and after incremental load on that fresh insert.how to lock the quarter data using SSIS or SQL server query.

Comment: You need to define “lock” and “freeze”. Do you just mean that you should no longer reload any data into those periods and they should remain static?

Comment: yes..no incremental load on freeze or locked data.It will remain static

Comment: Well.... see if you can make sense of my answer below.

Comment: This is why I rarely take time to answer questions properly.... the OP's just disappear or cannot grasp the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is create a calendar table and have a special column within that table that maps every single date to a 'freeze date' attribute.

So I leave you to do some research on calendar tables.

In the meantime, without a calendar table, here is something to get you started.

Firstly, this expression gives you the first month in the current quarter. So if today is anywhere within Jan - Mar, this expression gives you 1. If today is anywhere within Oct-Dec, it gives you 10

```
SELECT (((MONTH(GETDATE()))-1)/3)*3+1 As FirstMonthInCurrentQuarter
```

Now we convert that number to an actual date on the first of the month.

First, generate a numeric representation:

```
SELECT 
   YEAR(GETDATE()) * 10000 +
   ((((MONTH(GETDATE()))-1)/3)*3+1) * 100 +
   1
```

We just convert that to an actual date:

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(
       DATE,
           CAST(
            YEAR(GETDATE()) * 10000 +
            ((((MONTH(GETDATE()))-1)/3)*3+1) * 100 +
            1
            AS VARCHAR(8)),
        112)
```

That's a monstrous expression that can be replaced with a calendar table.

If you run it right now you'll get 1 Jan 2019. If you run that on 5th April you'll get 1st April. Hopefully you understand how that shuffles along automatically.

Now we use that date to decide what to load into your table.

```
DECLARE @LoadDate DATE

SET @LoadDate = 
   CONVERT(
       DATE,
           CAST(
            YEAR(GETDATE()) * 10000 +
            ((((MONTH(GETDATE()))-1)/3)*3+1) * 100 +
            1
            AS VARCHAR(8)),
        112)

-- Delete all the data in the target table after this date:
DELETE TargetTable WHERE TransactionDate >= @LoadDate;

-- Use your ETL tool to load this in:
INSERT INTO TargetTable (TransactionDate, Amount, Account)
SELECT TransactionDate, Amount, Account 
FROM SourceTable WHERE TransactionDate >= @LoadDate;
```

You have nowhere near enough information in your question for a meaningful answer, but maybe this will give you an idea

95% chance you never return though.